# Putting $\omega$ in two boxes

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

**Motivation.** My eldest son starts school tomorrow. His class is split in two groups of $10$ students each. From time to time, the groups are rearranged. I wondered how many rearrangements are needed until every student has been in the same group with every other student at least once. This led to a more general question.

**Question.** $f: \omega \to \{0,1\}$ is said to be *fair* if the preimages $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ are both infinite. Is there a positive integer $n$ and fair functions $f_i: \omega \to \{0,1\}$ for $i \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ with the following property?

> For all $a,b\in \omega$ there is $i \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $f_i(a) = f_i(b)$.

If yes, how small can $n$ be?

Comment: $f$ defined by $f(0)=0,f(a)=1$ for all $a>0$ deals with all pairs with $a,b>0$. It's easy to deal with the others using two more functions.

Comment: Right - in the school setting there was a "fair" distribution, I wanted this here too and formulated the question in a wrong way. Will correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $n=3$ and partition $\omega$ into three infinite sets, $X_0, X_1, X_2$. The functions $f_0,f_1,f_2$ defined by $$f_i(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{if $x$ belongs to } X_i \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ are fair functions, and for all $a, b \in \omega$ there is $i \in \{0,1,2\}$ such that $f_i(a) = f_i(b) = 0.$

On the other hand, this is impossible when $n=2$. If $f_0,f_1$ are any two fair functions from $\omega$ to $\{0,1\}$, assume without loss of generality that $f_0(0) = f_1(0) = 0$ and let $a,b \in \omega$ be such that $f_0(a)=1$ and $f_1(b)=1$. There must be $i \in \{0,1\}$ such that $f_i(a)=f_i(b)$. However, if $i=0$ then we have $f_0(b) = f_1(b) = 1$ so there is no $j \in \{0,1\}$ with $f_j(0) = f_j(b)$, while if $i=1$ then we have $f_0(a) = f_1(a) = 1$ so there is no $j \in \{0,1\}$ with $f_j(0) = f_j(a)$.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: For a solution which also works for finite classes of size divisible by $4$, partition the class into $4$ equal size blocks, $B_0$, $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$. On the first day, do $B_0 \cup B_1$ and $B_2 \cup B_3$, on the second day do $B_0 \cup B_2$ and $B_1 \cup B_3$ and on the third day do $B_0 \cup B_3$ and $B_1 \cup B_2$. (Perhaps name the blocks Gryffindor, Hufflepuff, Ravenclaw and Slytherin :) )